# How can I say strenuous/challenging without a negative connotation?

Tags: synonyms

I want to thank someone for a "challenging" semester - in the sense that it made me work really hard and was demanding, but in a good way

Comment: Challenging is not negative. In fact, it is exactly to word to use about an academic course that is hard in a good way without sounding like you are complaining that it is hard.

Comment: I agree. Challenging would be a great word to use.

Comment: i find a thesaurus is helpful in these situations

Answer (score 2):

The OP probably thinks challenging has a negative connotation, because in several of its meanings, it does.  But it has a positive connotation in the way the OP wants to use it.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/challenge), challenge can mean:

transitive verb:

> 1 : to dispute especially as being unjust, invalid, or outmoded :
>   impugn  //new data that challenges old assumptions
>
> 4 : to arouse or stimulate especially by presenting with difficulties 
>   //she wants a job that will challenge her
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1 : to make or present a challenge  //when the appropriate moment
>   challenged, he was capable of … leadership
>
> I've left out definitions 2a, 2b, 2c, 3, 5, 6, 7 for the transitive
>   verb and definition 2 for the intransitive.

As for **strenuous**, it also can have both negative and positive connotations.  According to [The Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/strenuous):

> strenuous: needing or using a lot of effort or energy

The word has a positive meaning if **strenuous exertion** is within the capability of the person exerting herself, and a negative meaning if the person is exerting herself beyond what is healthy for her.